# Как отличить содержимое картинки от текста

Tags: php

Есть картинка,которая грузится с другого сайта и отдаётся на нашем.Проблема заключается в том,что вместо картинки может отдаваться текст,похожий на `вы злой дядька ааа`.Как отличить картинку от текста после получения?

Comment: покажите пример того, как собственно получаете?

Comment: Читаете из файла первые несколько байт и сравниваете их с тем, что может быть в картинке. PNG имеет четкий заголовок, с JPG все хуже.

Comment: @Alexander Igorevich Картинок много и с разных сайтов и в разных форматах...

Comment: Безотносительно к вопросу. Что мешает написать на картинке вы злой дядька ааа?

Comment: @Ипатьев Ничего.Но огромная часть сайтов отдаёт такого подобия текст.Так что если проскочит - не страшно. Источников много

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Смотреть на код ответа.
2. Смотреть на mime-type.
3. Обратить внимание на html-разметку.
4. Обратить внимание на количество пробелов и среднюю длину слов.
5. Проверить, что префикс файла соответствует графическому формату.
6. Подумать об svg.
7. Написать систему распознавания текста на картинке аля FineReader :)

---

Если один и тот же сайт так поступает, то, вероятно, он поступает так со всеми своими картинками, так что взять десяток разных картинок и сравнить, одинаково ли он ответил на все вопросы. Если данные одинаковы, то это какая-то заглушка.

---

Раз речь идёт об определении на сервере (на клиенте оно невозможно в силу политик кроссдоменности), то что мешает корректно выставить заголовок `referer`, чтобы тот сервер даже и не узнал, что запросы идут с другого сайта? Соответственно, своему сайту проксировать картинки.

---

Впрочем, от бана за количество запросов это не очень поможет. Но можно прикрутить какие-нибудь прокси.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте расширение `finfo`. Оно умеет определять mime-тип не только по файлу, но и из строкового буфера.

```
<?php
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
echo $finfo->buffer($data);
```

Посмотрите, как определяются ваши картинки, создайте белый список корректных типов, остальное считайте не картинкой.